# No encuentro la carpeta de android emulated/0/

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, makefile, filesystem

Estoy creando un fichero público en una ruta de android, he seguido los pasos de la web android developer.

Trato de crear una carpeta en pictures, he depurado y todo funciona bien, pero cuando veo el celular no encuentro dicha carpeta. También he buscado al conectar el celular a la pc y nada. Estoy confundido, aquí la foto.

Quiero añadir que en todos las funciones boolean me den true. Estoy probando con un celular motorola moto c.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te marca en las lineas en rojo de tu código ?

Comment: Acostumbra agregar texto en lugar de imagen de código. Además es importante agregar los mensajes desplegados en el LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcta la forma como creas tu folder dentro del directorio para almacenar fotos, **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/**

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
```

El problema en este caso son los permisos, debes definir dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` el permiso:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Para android 6.0 o posterior debe ser manual la petición:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

Comment: Cuando marquen un -1 podrían minino explicar el por que ...

Comment: @Ash hehe, estoy acostumbrandome a esto, mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114263/err-unknown-url-scheme-chrome-webview-client-android-html-file-href-tel/114287#114287  la persona me puntua negativo pero al mismo tiempo a la otra "respuesta" le da un punto positivo, en realidad la otra "respuesta" es una edición del OP, pero no comenta porque razón tengo -1 .

Comment: La gente esta muy loca .. Jaja

Comment: @Ash a donde puede llegar la mente de un desarrollador, puede desvariar haha :D