# Marcacion de numero de telefono desde Android Studio

Tags: android

he puesto en Android Studio una pagina web con números de teléfonos y correos, la pagina para el correo tiene el código mailto:nombre@gmail.com y para el teléfono tel:666666666, esta pagina funciona de forma independiente, pero al ponerla en Android Studio y crear el apk, al pulsas sobre sobre el numero o el correo muestra un mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que poner otro codigo en la pagina web para que al pulsar sobre el numero y el correo nos muestre el marcador telefónico o el gestor de correo ?

Tabla en htm

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>telefonos</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">

<div class="rvps4">
<table width="567" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border-spacing: 1.5pt; font-size: 14pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px auto">
 <tr valign="top">
  <td width="327" height="38" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #00ffff;" align="center">
  <p class="rvps3"><span class="rvts7">Nombre</span></td>
  <td width="117" height="38" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #ccffcc;" align="center">
  <p class="rvps3"><span class="rvts6">Telf.</span></td>
  <td width="97" height="38" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #ffff99;" align="center">
  <p class="rvps3"><span class="rvts6">Correo</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr valign="top">
  <td width="327" height="33" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #ccffff;">
  <p class="rvps2"><span class="rvts9">xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx </span></td>
  <td width="117" height="33" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #ccffcc;">
  <p class="rvps3" align="center">
  <a class="rvts13" title="Exterior" href="tel:999999999">999999999</a></td>
  <td width="97" height="33" valign="middle" style="border-style: inset; padding: 1.5pt; background-color: #ffff99;">
  <p class="rvps3" align="center">
  <a class="rvts8" title="e-mail" href="mailto:correo@gmanil.com">
  e-mail</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y desde android studio la muestro con este codigo

```js
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rcf, container, false);

        webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pagina.htm");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return view;
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que estas usando para tener mas contexto

Comment: Agrega tu código html y como lo cargas en el WebView @Socu esto para que sea de más ayuda a otros usuarios tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, no recibo notificaciones de nuevas respuestas, he puesto el codigo arriba, Jorgesys en el proyecto que te pase con el link en el otro post estaba puesto esto que pregunto. Por otro lado sigo sin poder puntuaros, no me sale la opción.

Comment: amigo @Bruno Sosa Fast Tag, ya puse el codigo, es lo que preguntas, como es que desde la pagina htm si me muestra el marcador del telefono para hacer la llamada, y cuando pongo la pagina y creo el apk no me muestra el marcador, me muestra el error que he puesto en el primer mensaje ?

Answer (score 1):

Espero este ejemplo te sea de ayuda

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebpage.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );
            return true;
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:open_menu()");
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bruno siento no responder antes, no he visto tu respuesta, tengo un pequeño problema no se si tiene solución, el código que tengo esta como `public class Telefonos extends Fragment {` al poner como `public class Telefonos extends AppCompatActivity {`en el MainActivity tengo un menú desde el que llamo a `Telefonos()` que me muestra un error y si lo cambio por Fragment el código me muestra muchos errores. Todas las clases las tengo creadas con Fragment, porque abren páginas web, no si si para este codigo y para los demas tiene solución y poder cambiarlos todos a AppCompatActivity

Comment: Bueno pues lo dicho Bruno gracias, pero no soy capaz de seguir buscando una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Para que soporte el esquema agrega un signo "+" , por ejemplo:

Teniendo como ejemplo el telefono `347 555666777`, esta sería la definición en el html:

```
tel:+347 555666777
```

Revisa esta pregunta relacionada, en la cual realiza la marcación pero por medio de un `Intent`:

[ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Chrome webview client android html file href="tel:"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114263/err-unknown-url-scheme-chrome-webview-client-android-html-file-href-tel)