# Abrir clase activity desde menú TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

no sé muy buen como plantear esta pregunta, tengo creado en el MainActivity un menú desde cual llamo a las clases Fragments, pero quiero cambiar o crear las clases Fragment por Clases AppCompatActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 1", R.drawable.menu1_icon,true);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.menu2_icon);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.menu3_icon);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.menu4_icon);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.menu5_icon);

    horizontal_menu.showItems();

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

    });

    horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    });

}


private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Menu_1();
            case 1:
                return new Menu_2();
            case 2:
                return new Menu_3();
            case 3:
                return new Menu_4();
            case 4:
                return new Menu_5();
            default:
                return new Menu_1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Lo que pasa es que ahora en el menú me muestra errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Menu_1.java**

```
public class Menu_1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.menu_1 );

    String url = "file:///android_asset/menu_1.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Me podéis ayudar y decir cómo cambiar ese menú para utilizar las clases Activitys, o bien si se pueden tener las dos Fragmensts y Activitys

Gracias.

Comment: Si necesitas un menu , lo mas rapido es crear un proyecto nuevo y elegir el template de navigationDrawer robartelo y pasarlo a tu app

Comment: La respuesta mas corta es, en un `FragmentPagerAdapter` no puedes usar como items actividades. Esta diseñado para trabajar con `fragments`. Por que quieres utilizar actividades?

Comment: Pues el proyecto de menú que estoy utilizando lo cree para abrir páginas web localmente, y necesito utilizar el botón atrás para moverme por las páginas web y los menús, con las clases fragmen por más que he preguntado y probado código no he conseguido que funcione la flecha atrás que sale en el menú Toolbar, luego tengo creado un mapa también en un archivo htm, que parece que por culpa de estar en un fragmen no me deja utilizar el mapa, y el proyecto del menú que estoy utilizando me gustaría seguir utilizándolo, y otra pagina con telefonos que no consigo hacer llamadas, todas utilizan Fragmen

Comment: SoCu, te sugiero que cambies las clases que intentas crear en el PagerAdapter a Fragments, posteriormente vuelvas a preguntar  si tienes problema en la implementación.

Comment: Porque Jorgesys no se puede crear un menú para abrir clases Activity en lugar de Fragment ? lo pregunto porque intento buscar un código de ejemplo para probar y no he visto nada, por lo menos en páginas y youtube en español.  
Ya he vuelto a dejar todas las clases como Fragment, y dices que vuela a preguntar, tengo este tema abierto y sin terminar, creo que, por este problema, el ejemplo Bruno está en una clase Activity, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124811/marcacion-de-numero-de-telefono-desde-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo tu pregunta y no hay una solucion a lo que tu quieres. Primero que nada entendamos la naturaleza de el actiivity y de los fragments. Un activity es la unidad basica de desarrollo la cual me permite acceder a todos los elementos del sistema. Estos activities al tener esta naturaleza deben ser NOMBRADOS Y DEFINIDOS previamente en el manifest y cuentan con un ciclo de vida el cual es diferente al de los fragments (Te recomiendo que leas un poco acerca de estos ciclos de vida). Por otra parte los fragments solo elementos que pueden encapsular logica y vista y adicional a ello pueden ser asignados, borrados y creados de manera dinamica, por lo cual son muy utiles para crear por ejemplo tabs o menu laterales. Piensalo de esta manera, al momento de crear un menu lateral estas creando porciones de vista con logica los cuales se crean, se asignan y se ligan a la pantalla de manera dinamica (cuando presionas un boton del menu lateral una vista se va y otra entra), para esto debes usar fragments ya que no puedes hacer lo mismo con activities.

Dicho de otra manera, no puede usar activities para crear un menu lateral, debes usar fragments.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Jhon, si algún día resuelvo los problemas que no me dejan terminar la aplicación, y que por los post que tengo creados no tengo mucha suerte, tengo pensado agregar un menú lateral como bien dices, pero eso lo dejo a ver si puedo encontrar por algún lado como poder seguir avanzando.

Comment: Vale amigo, si te recomiendo que intentes usar cada componente para lo cual fueron creados :D, cuando le tomes el tiro se va a hacer mucho mas fácil ya veras. Si esta respuesta te parece correcta te agradecería que la seleccionaras como respuesta correcta. Gracias